# onStartCommand is never invoked

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I'm running a service from MainActivity by

```
startService(mServiceIntent)
```

But there is only onCreate method invoked.I need to collect some extras arguments from Intent so I want to onStartCommand to be invoked too. Do You know what is the reason it's not happening. My Service code.

```
class ImportantService : Service() {

    var phoneListener : MyPhoneStateListener? = null
    var listening = false
    var telephony: TelephonyManager? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        TODO("Return the communication channel to the service.")
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("ImportantService", "On Create")
        //startListen()
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ch1")
                    .setContentText("Content text")
                    .setContentTitle("Content title")
            startForeground(101,builder.build())
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        // this method is never invoked
        Log.d("ImportantService", "On Start")
        if(listening)
        {
            Log.d("ImportantService", "Started")
            startListen()
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("ImportantService", "Stopped")
           // stopListen()
        }

    }


    fun startListen()
    {
        Log.d("Service", "startListen")
     
    }  
}
```

Comment: Any good IDE should have warned you that the code after the `return` statement was not accessible. Paying attention to the warnings from the IDE is useful, and can save a lot of time in troubleshooting. This is a perfect example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to move `return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)` to the end of your function.